# JMeter Test Plan Login Issue

Tags: jmeter

I was hoping someone could shine some light on my problem. I am in the process of load testing a website. For authenticity, I would like to simulate users logging in and such. JMeter refuses to comply. I have tried manually using HTTPS requests, HTTPS spoofing that is provided, and exporting login scripts from Badboy. Using the View Results Tree listener after running a test, it seems that everything is working, but in the end I am always redirected to the login page. The cookie appears to be functioning properly as it displays the same session for each request.

Thanks in advance for any wisdom you all may offer.

Comment: is there any error in the jmeter.log?

Comment: No errors in the log file. There are a few warnings about an Existing Header Manager, but I don't believe that is any issue. I used Badboy on Amazon to log in and examine old orders. Exporting that test plan to JMeter was a success, as it ran fine. Evidently, it is our site that isn't cooperating, not JMeter.

Comment: have you checked your redirect options?  I've had that bite me several times.

Comment: Everything is set up to follow redirects. I attempted the test again with the major new release of JMeter, but it was still unsuccessful. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does your webapp only support a specific browser, like IE6?  If so, you may need to add a header manager

Answer (score 2):

While badboy is a great tool to create jmeter test in https.

But on our apps, badboy seem to add get request that didn't work at all, I had to remove them manually to fix the problem.

And if you have a token or session id in your cookies, it's doesn't take care of it for you so you got to figure out how to extract them with a reg-ex extrator and put in a variable that your test will use.

These problem were very specific to our apps not sure it apply to you, but if you remove unessary request and take care of sending back your token/session id it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue sometime ago but since my web application was JSF based I had to take care of the javax.faces.ViewState.

In my case every response had a JFV and I had to pass it as a parameter to the next request using Regular Expression Extractor.
Kindly check if your application is having any such problem.

Regards